# Postgres anonymous block execution of generated dynamic sql to drop databases

Tags: postgresql

I have backup databases I wish to drop. I can generate a list :

```
select 'drop database ' || datname || ' ;' from pg_database where datname like 'bak_%'
```

getting me

```
drop database bak_20180101 ;
drop database bak_20180102 ;
```

etc

but when I try

```
Do $$Begin execute 'drop database $1 ;' Using  'bak_20180404_2014_12' ; End$$ ;
```

that gets me `syntax error at or near "$1"`

and when I try

```
Do $$Begin execute 'drop database bak_20180404_2014_12' ; End$$ ;
```

that gets me `DROP DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string`

Is there a simple way to drop a generated list of databases?
(and what was wrong with my Execute Using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass identifiers as parameters, you need to create a dynamic string. The best way to do that is to use `format()`

```
Do $$
Begin 
   execute format('drop database %I ', 'bak_20180404_2014_12'); 
End
$$ ;
```

You can combine that with a loop:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
begin
  for l_rec in select datname from pg_database where datname like 'bak_%' 
  loop
     execute format('drop database %I ', l_rec.datname); 
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

---

**Edit**

I always forget that you can't drop a database like that. But in `psql` you can easily run the result of a query as a script:

```
postgres=> select 'drop database '||datname||';' from pg_database 
postgres-> \gexec
```

Note the missing `;` at the end of the `select` statement. When you terminate the query with `\gexec` instead of `;` the query's result will be executed as a script.

Another option is to simply spool the output to a file, so that you can inspect the drop statements before running them:

```
postgres=> \t
Tuples only is on.
postgres=> \o drop.sql
postgres=> select 'drop database '||datname||';' from pg_database;
postgres=> \o
postgres=> \i drop.sql
```

Comment: and ... is there a way past `DROP DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string` ? (on pg9.6)

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll: ah, right I always forget that. If you are using `psql` there is an easy workaround.

Comment: Alas. But not a big deal. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll: see my edit

Comment: Perfect! thankyou. I think the \gexec is what I was looking for.